# flask-socketio when are room-events executed

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I'm just getting started with flask-socketio and am wondering, when are the room-events executed?

The Background:

I wait for an custom event, lets call it `addUser`. When that Event is sent from the client, I execute `join_room('roomName')`. Then I'd expect the `create-room` event if the room isn't created. In the `create-room` event-handler, I initialize some datastructure which I need in the handler of `addUser`. Now somehow I don't ever get the `create-room` Event.

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit, join_room, leave_room, rooms
...

rid2Game = {}

@socketio.on('addUser')
def addUser(rid, uid):
    print('New user %s -> %s joining' % (request.sid, uid))
    join_room(rid)
    # time.sleep(10)
    rid2Game[str(rid)].connect(request.sid, uid) # this depends on the initialization of create-room
# (this is a threading thing too, but I thought, at least
# for testing with the waiting above this would have to work)

@socketio.on('create-room')
def createRoom(rid):
    print("Add room %s" % rid)
    rid2Game[str(rid)] = game.Game() # some initialization
```

What is it I'm doing wrong? (And maybe someone even has an idea for the threading thing)

Comment: Just tried the whole thing without the `rid2Game[str(rid)].connect(request.sid, uid)` to check if the room-events ever come. And no the don't. For me this looks like a big error or some misconfiguration

Comment: Or is it possible that `flask-socketio` don't even uses these events? (Just thought it does since I read it in the socketio, but now after searching, I cannot find something about it in the `flask-socketio` doc)

Comment: Flask-SocketIO is not a port of the JavaScript version. Lots of things are different. The `create-room` event does not exist. Also note that it is also very new for the JS server.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Then this is my mistake by looking into the wrong documentation. Then I'll just keep track of whats happening and which rooms are already present myself. Thanks for your answer